# VLAN Creation on Juniper QFX5100

Tags: vlan, juniper-junos

1) I am able to create VLAN on Juniper QFX5100 but when I am assigning     interface to that VLAN it is showing an error "family ethernet-switching and other families are mutually exclusive"

Command used is

```
set vlans Customer1 vlan-id 11

set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members Customer1
```

On this interface I have already configured IP address

2) But when I am creating vlans on some other port with nothing configured on it, I am able to create the vlan

Command used is

```
set vlans Customer1 vland-id 11

Set interfaces ge-0/0/20.0 family ethernet-switching vlan members Customer1
```

This interface does not have any IP address configured on it.

And 1 more thing I would like to add is in 2nd query in commands if I am not adding .0 to the interface (i.e. ge-0/0/20.0) it will not showing me option of family after interface ge-0/0/20.0

Please help me to resolve this issue as i am just new to Juniper.

Comment: Could you post your full configuration, please?

Comment: Sorry, full interface configuration - "show configuration interfaces"

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  family ethernet-switching and other families are mutually exclusive
> ```

You're using too many parameters under the `family` stanza.  This extra parameter is `family inet` based on this:

> *”On this interface I have already configured IP address.”*

Run `user@qfx5100# delete interfaces ge-0/0/0.0 family inet`.  Optionally, you could delete all of ge-0/0/0.0 with `user@qfx5100# delete interfaces ge-0/0/0.0` and then put your configurations back in.

When running `show interfaces` and `show vlans`, you should see this:

```
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members Customer1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/20 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members Customer1;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
vlans {
    Customer1 {
        vland-id 11;
    }
}
```